# Safari cannot connect to web server via ssl protocol

Tags: tomcat, ssl, safari

I wrote my own web server run on tomcat. I also configured it to be able to connect to web server by SSL protocol.
I can connect to link `https://[server address]:8443/[WebServer]` by Firefox. But when I open the link  by Safari, it displays failed page.

Comment: Could you provide the error message? If I am to guess, with the limited information provided you have trust issues with the certificate.

Comment: Hi.The message safari let me know is "Safari can't open the page https://[server address]:8443/[WebServer] because Safari can't establish a secure connection to the server". Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a `keychain` problem in your `Safari`. No `https` page works, not just your site. Correct? After some searching I found this that might help you:

[safari cant connect to https](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53562/safari-cant-connect-to-https)

Basically you want to recreate your `keychain` and this seem to be done by removing (Renamning might be clever to save them as backups) your

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.plist
```

and/or

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.revocation.plist
```

and try again. You probably need to restart Safari. I am not running Safari myself, but hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying. My Safari can connect to https://www.facebook.com,https://www.google.com but only for my local page, it cannot connect.

Comment: Life saver! Removing `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.revocation.plist` allowed me to visit https websites in Safari again, including browsing the Mac App Store!

Answer (score 0):

You're not mentioning what kind of error message you get. I'm assuming that you get a message like "the server is not trusted" - e.g. you most likely use a self-signed certificate on tomcat. Part of SSL is that the server's public key is signed (certified) by a trusted entity, ensuring that the used key actually matches the domain name. This is being used so that you can't easily imitate being a different server if you want to attack its users.

Most likely you have worked around this requirement by signing your key yourself. This means that browsers will deny a connection until you specifically state that you trust the key (otherwise the trusted signature will imply that trust).

How do you know if you're using a self-signed vs. a "trusted" key? If you have passed money to someone in order to sign your key, you might be using a trusted one. If you have not passed money to anyone to sign your key, you're using an untrusted - most likely self-signed - key.

I guess that you earlier manually accepted this key in Firefox and have forgotten about it. I don't know what Safari displays in order to get the key accepted (or if it's configurable to just deny untrusted keys and not ask any question). So from here you'll have to find the way yourself, I hope that the explanations above help you to make sense of the error message you see. It might make sense to add the actual error message to your question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The message safari let me know is "Safari can't open the page https://[server address]:8443/[WebServer] because Safari can't establish a secure connection to the server", and I don't know why.

Comment: Safari "can't establish a secure connection" exactly because it doesn't trust the (likely self-signed) public key the server presents. While encryption would work, you have no clue who you are communicating with - thus Safari doesn't trust it and refuses to connect. I don't know how to convince Safari to manually override this trust for your site. Firefox offers this option on the page of the equivalent error message.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your self signed certificate is not expired. For example, open website in Chrome or Firefox and explore certificate details, in particular validity dates.